# JqueryMobile Data Grid with pagination

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using Jquery mobile with phone gap to write a mobile application,Is there any data grid with pagination in jquerymobile?

Thank you

Comment: No. Large grids are not usually the best way of displaying data on such a small screen. There are a few options. JqM has tables, you could add in your own custom pagination there. Or you could search SO for questions on JS grid libraries e.g. https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at FooTable ( http://themergency.com/footable/ ). It has pagination as an option as well as the ability to show fewer columns on smaller phones via expandable rows.

Answer (score 1):

the pagination should be made in your server, no matter how good can be your jquery pagination plugin: it requires all the data to be paginated later in client side causing a mobile overhelming ram and processor due to large data.

the best way to achieve this is in mobile or desktop is:

1. Start you query: "give the name of the pacient: [Jhon] ",  ohh my
   god, 10.000 Jhon were found in the database.  So, instead of
   returning the entire list having 10.000 records then return a
   object: { currentpage: 0, pages: 10 , recordsperpage: 1000 }  (ok
   1000 records per page is a lot, so it is a example)
2. Then, the same action in your serverside can receive an argument:
   "page=2" (to receive records) or "page=null" (to return the counter
   in step1, this is the initial status)
3. The server side will return records only when a argument is explicit
   to that point.